# How to save pygame window as a image? (python3) (PyGame)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a pixel editor / a trash version of ms paint in python with pygame, and I want to save the window (canvas?) as a png or jpg. I've seen pygame.image.save, but that only saves a certain surface as an image, I want to save the entire window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pygame.image.save()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save), which requires PyGame 1.8 or later.  If you give it the base-level window surface, it will indeed save the entire window content.

For example:

```
pygame.image.save( window, 'surface.png' )
```

The image type is determined by the filename suffix.

Comment: How would I make it automatically download the image?

Comment: Also, what if I just want to save part of the window?

Comment: What do you mean "download the image" download to where? How?

Comment: @FluffyFlounder to save part of an image, you can create a new Surface of the required size, `blit()` part of the background to it, then use `save()` on that sub-image.

Answer (score 4):

Give the following a try:

```
pygame.image.save(window, "screenshot.png")
```